# Spring Data Elasticsearch w/ Elasticsearch 6.2.1

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to get Spring Data Elasticsearch to work with `Spring-Boot-1.5.9.RELEASE`.

I realize that so far the only *supported* version is [up to 5.5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch) @ 3.0.0.RC2, I realized there is a pull-request [supporting 6.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/195), so I tried to compile and run it, but it played hell on the rest of the Spring-boot configurations as it requires a later version of `spring-data-core`.

I'm also wondering if this is all pointless, as we're using hosted Elasticsearch and it maybe only accessible over HTTP (on [Elastic Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud))

Thoughts?